# Text selection on double click in HTML with a float

Tags: html

With the subsequent code :

```html
<span>Label1 Label2</span>
<span style="float:left"><span>Value</span></span>
```

when double-clicking on the "Value" word, Label2 is selected (highlited) but not Label1.
Why is this the case ?

What can I do to select only the "Value" word and none of the "Label" words ?

Live example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IHDzj

Edit: this bug only exists in Chrome

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is possibly the Chrome issue. Because in Firefox it works fine. However to solve it in chrome just add space before closing of first span tag as shown here.

```
<span>Label1 Label2 </span>
<span style="float:left"><span>Value</span></span>
```

Because whenever we select a text by doubleclicking it.The word as well as white space got selected in chrome and this bug has already fired in chromium issue.

Comment: I'll use this, because I also need to select my labels. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the property `user-select: none` for the labels so that it wont get selected on clicking.This property is vendor specific.

html

```
<span id = "label1">Label1 Label2</span>
<span style="float:left"><span>Value</span></span>
```

css

```
#label1 {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/8oz6rccm/)

Reference[:Stack Overflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

Read more on [user-select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select)

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm, that I had the same problem in Chrome, but not in Firefox. The solution I used was to add a space before `Value` like so:

```
<span>Label1 Label2</span>
<span style="float:left"><span> Value</span></span>
```

The solution by [Roshan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25201132/1836143) didn't work for me, because double clicking `Value` would also select the space after `Label2`.

Answer (score 1):

My problem might be a bit different, since I used float: right on the second node.

```css
.property-title {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
}

.property-value {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<li data-name="article-number">
  <span class="property-title">Label</span>
  <span class="property-value">Value</span>
</li>
```

The suggested solution from [Roshan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25201132/2526914) didn't work for me. I ended up adding a `&nbsp;` after the first node.

```
<li data-name="article-number">
  <span class="property-title">Artikelnummer</span>&nbsp;
  <span class="property-value">8C32345</span>
</li>
```